# Faster/Easier method of finding number of duplicates of values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I am currently using a `HashMap` to correspond the duplicate values and the number of times they are repeated. Its `linear efficiency O(n)` but I was looking for some built-in methods or a faster way to calculate the number of duplicates for each value in an array (like `O(log n)`)?.

Here is my current shot that works:

```
String[] array = {"Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Maxwell", "Maxwell"};

HashMap<String, Integer> duplicates = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int numberOfDuplicates = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (duplicates.put(array[i], numberOfDuplicates) != null) // Duplicate Key
    {
        numberOfDuplicates++;
    }
    else // New Key
    {
        numberOfDuplicates = 1;
    }

    duplicates.put(array[i], numberOfDuplicates);
}


// Print out duplicate counts
for (String key : duplicates.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " " + duplicates.get(key));
}
```

What about a faster way/pragmatic way? 10Q.

Comment: You can't do it faster than linear time complexity.

Comment: @Eran Ok, but is their any built-in method?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. If you've got it to O(n) there's no reason to try to improve it, and the standard SDK doesn't have a method for this. Your code could look better though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could always use a multiset, such as from Guava, but it's basically doing this same thing.

Comment: If you really needed a speed increase I'd consider a few options. 1. Check that sorting and counting is not faster, it may be O(n log n ) but the constant can be much lower since it doesn't need to do any allocations. 2. Consider using one of the maps from a Trove (or similar) since they're optimized to not use Integer, but actually use `int`. Which means less overheads and they're fast. (and I think they can be set to default initialize to zero, and have an increment function...)

Comment: You might optimze your code (not the logic) if you have perfomance issues `containsKey(k) instead of put(k, v)` / want to reduce the gc (get rid of the autoboxing of the counter`. Using a `Set` of name objects (which contains the field `name` and an `int` counter might also a solution. All depends on what you want to achive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it with less code using Java 8 Streams :

```
Map<String, Integer> duplicates =
    Arrays.stream(array)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, 
                                         Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at removing some of the clutter.

```
String[] array = {"Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Maxwell", "Maxwell"};

HashMap<String, Integer> duplicates = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String s : array) {
    Integer i = duplicates.get(s);
    duplicates.put(s, i == null ? 1 : (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can do it in following way

```
        if(duplicates.containsKey(array[i])){
            duplicates.put(array[i],duplicates.get(array[i])+1);
        }else{
            duplicates.put(array[i], 1);
        }
```

instead of

```
if (duplicates.put(array[i], numberOfDuplicates) != null) // Duplicate Key
    {
        numberOfDuplicates++;
    }
    else // New Key
    {
        numberOfDuplicates = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Trove Version

This is  a modification of Kayamans answer using Trove, which is a high-performance collection library.

```
String[] array = {"Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Maxwell", "Maxwell"};

TObjectIntMap<String> duplicates = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
for(String s: array) {
   duplicates.adjustOrPutValue(s,1,1);
}

duplicates.forEachEntry( new TObjectIntProcedure<String>() {
   void execute(String key, int value) {
      System.out.println(key + " " + value);
   };  
});
```

### In place sort version

This version uses `Arrays.sort` and then steps through the array reporting duplicates. While `Arrays.sort` is `O(n log n)` the resulting algorithm  may be faster due to it avoiding any allocations of data-structures - but it does change the order of the input array.

*NOTE 1:* In this case the timing will be  dominated by the IO calls, so you may not notice the speed.

*NOTE 2:* I'd refactor and extract the core of this and use a functor to handle the processing of the duplicates.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
String last = null;
int count = 0;
for(String v:array) {

    // Is it the first value
    if(last = null) {
       last = v;
       count = 1;
       continue;
    }

    // Have we started a new value?
    if(last.equals(v)) {
       System.out.println(last + " " +count);
       last = v;
       count = 1;
       continue;
    }

    // Its a repeated value.
    ++count;
}

if(last!=null)
   System.out.println(last + " " +count);
```